# Jquery promise wait to ajax end

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm getting predefined values, which i have to insert into two selects:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <select id="first">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="second"></select>
</div>
```

Options inside `#second` depends on selected value in `#first`. This options are loaded via ajax:

```
$('#first').change( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "giveMeValues.phpOrWhatever"
        }).done(function() {
            // just simulating data from ajax call
            $('#second').append(
                '<option value="a">a</option>'+
                '<option value="b">b</option>'+
                '<option value="c">c</option>'
            );
        });
    });
```

The problem is, I can set value of `#second` **after** ajax data will be loaded. So following code will of course not work:

```
$('#first').val('2').change();
$('#second').val('b').change();
```

So i tried to use `.promise()` to wait untill ajax call inside `change` handler will be completed:

```
$('#first').val('2').change();
    $('#wrapper').promise().then( function() {
        $('#second').val('b');
        console.log('setting value...');
    });
```

But it doesn't work. My question is: how i can wait to end of ajax call, and then set `#second` value?

Here you have fiddle for this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/W2nVd/

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the promise from the ajax like so:

```
(function($) {
    // Our Ajax promise variable
    var promise;

    $('#first').change( function() {
        // Set the ajax promise variable
        promise = $.ajax({
            url: "#"
        }).done(function() {
            $('#second').append(
                '<option value="a">a</option>'+
                '<option value="b">b</option>'+
                '<option value="c">c</option>'
            );
            console.log('appending new content...');
        });
    });

    $('#first').val('2').change();
    // the var `promise` was set on the line above when it executed 
    // the `change()` callback
    promise.promise().done( function() {
        $('#second').val('b');
        console.log('setting value...');
    });

})(jQuery);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W2nVd/2/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing some of your workflow requirements, but can't you just set the value of #second after you append the options?

```
$.ajax({
            url: "#"
        }).done(function() {
            $('#second').empty().append(
                '<option value="a">a</option>'+
                '<option value="b">b</option>'+
                '<option value="c">c</option>'
            );
            $('#second').val('b');
            console.log('appending new content...');
        });
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W2nVd/1/

Comment: I was thinking about it too, but the problem is, this change should be set only one time. With your code, allways after changing `#first` `#second` will be set to `'b'`.

Answer (score 0):

.done() is exactly what you are searching for just put it inside..like so

try ...

```
$('#first').change( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "giveMeValues.phpOrWhatever"
    }).done(function() {
        // just simulating data from ajax call
        $('#second').append(
            '<option value="a">a</option>'+
            '<option value="b" selected="selected">b</option>'+
            '<option value="c">c</option>'
        );
    });
});
```

.... or.....

```
$('#first').change( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "giveMeValues.phpOrWhatever"
    }).done(function() {
        // just simulating data from ajax call
        $('#second').append(
            '<option value="a">a</option>'+
            '<option value="b">b</option>'+
            '<option value="c">c</option>'
        );
        $('#second').val('b'); // change value after options are available


    });
});
```

Comment: I was thinking about it too, but the problem is, this change should be set **only one time**. With your code, allways after changing #first #second will be set to 'b'

Comment: ok..? but also it will  do the Ajax-call and append 3 more optionsevery time...so do you want to this everytime you change #first? or the whole function should only execute once?

Comment: It was just simplification as my comment noticed: `// just simulating data from ajax call`. In real situation, this values will depends on selected option.